# Use data from CSV file to print out the year, month, and associated value > 170

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am very new to programming and am stuck on a homework question. I am not looking for straight out answers, rather for someone to explain the steps I should take.

Here are my current steps and output:

Input:

```
data_new = np.loadtxt('lecture14_precipitation.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
arr_years = np.arange(1916,2017, dtype = 'int')
arr_months = np.arange(1,13, dtype = 'int')
new = np.where(data_new > 170)
for a,b in zip(arr_years,arr_months):
    print(a,b,data_new[new])
```

Output:

```
1916 1 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1917 2 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1918 3 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1919 4 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1920 5 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1921 6 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1922 7 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1923 8 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1924 9 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1925 10 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1926 11 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
1927 12 [181.9 189.3 198.7 185.9 175.6 203.  186.4 175.4 177.3 176.3]
```

I have uploaded the csv file, it has 12 columns and 100 rows (representing the 12 months and 100 year span). I have been able to extract all values above 170 from the file, but I am struggling to match them to their specific columns and rows (months & years). I am looking to have each value over 170 be matched to the specific year and month associated with it.

Comment: Do you mind showing an output of what is desired for more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use from dictionary to store them:

eg:

```
all_data = list()

for a,b in zip(arr_years,arr_months):
    temp_dict = dict()
    temp_dict["year"]  = a
    temp_dict["month"] = b
    temp_dict["data"]  = data_new[new]
    all_data.append(temp_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# get the (x, y) indices of values > 170
idx = np.where(data_new > 170)

# yr = x_indices + 1916 (assuming 1916 is the lowest year and yearly frequency)
yr, mn = idx[0] + 1916, idx[1]

# create a dictionary where the key is a tuple (year, month) and 
# the value is the value of that cell in your `data_new`
over_170 = dict(zip(zip(yr, mn), data_new[idx]))
```